# Save, fetch, and call on user data in DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, database, datagridview, fetch

I am currently working on a cost estimator for our construction team. I various interlinked windows forms that the user is able to enter site information, and then generate an excel quote. My problem is that I need a place for non-site variables, such as concrete cost, gravel cost, etc that the user can adjust based on location (we are cross country).

I am attempting to set up a DataGridView with the columns of "Item", "Description" "Unit size" and "Cost per unit". All are locked except for the cost per unit, which the user can adjust based on location and time of year.

I write the data to an XML file, and then am attempting to bring back that data (with any changes they made) the next time they open the DataGridView. This is where my problem is. It looks like I am getting a successful write when I go and view the XML file itself, but the information is not pulling in. How can I accomplish this? My code is listed below. Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class frmCostConfig : Form
    {

        public frmCostConfig()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CostConfig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = "C:\\Cost Configuration.xml";
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(fileName);

                dataCostConfig.DataSource = ds;
            }
        }

        private void btnSaveAllData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();            
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Cost Configuration");

            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Unit of Measure", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Cost per Unit", typeof(string));
            foreach (DataGridViewRow datarow in this.dataCostConfig.Rows)
            {
                DataRow myrow = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i <= dataCostConfig.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    myrow[i] = datarow.Cells[i].Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(myrow);
            }
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            dataCostConfig.DataSource = ds;

            DataSet dataSet = (DataSet)dataCostConfig.DataSource;
            dataSet.WriteXml("C:\\Cost Configuration.xml");
            this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Add the schema to the WriteXml(filename, schema) method [second parameter].

Comment: Didn't work. I changed to WriteXml(fileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema) but nothing changed. I then attempted to change the readXml to ReadXml(fileName,XmlReadMode.ReadSchema) which also didn't work.

Comment: Make sure the data is getting saved in the xml file by opening with notepad (or any text reader).  I think you issue may be the refresh method for DGV.  The DGV doesn't automatically update when the DataSource changes.  So the trick is to set to null. dataCostConfig.DataSource = null;dataCostConfig.DataSource = ds;

Comment: Tried that as well before.

I can go to the actual XML file and everything that I saved originally when clicking my button is there. When I close the form containing the DataGridView and reopen it, it is simply a blank row containing my headers and nothing else.

Thanks for the help though! Good to get suggestions/ideas. Maybe I'm missing something really silly. Fairly new to programming and this is my first C# Application (done a couple in VB but that's the extent of my skill!)

Comment: Change the load method from : CostConfig() to : frmCostConfig();  Then add following after intialize : InitializeComponent();this.Load += new EventHandler(frmCostConfig_Load);
        }

Comment: No luck there either :(

Perhaps my method of loading the dataset isn't the best. Are there other ways to load the dataset based on how I am saving information? I'm still getting an XML file that contains all the info I type in initially, so I would assume that indicates a load/read problem.

Comment: The data should match what you see using notepad.  If you are getting different results then you must be looking/reading the wrong file.